# Visual Studio 2013 Source not available (can't debug)

Tags: vb.net, debugging, symbols

I suddently can't debug (in debug mode) on a VB.NET project developed on Visual Studio 2013 Community.

VS says first it can't load the symbols. I load them using the symbol servers and then it says I can't debug. The message says "No source available" (although it's definitely my code).

In the project's property I have activated the debug mode with full info and debug and trace active.

"Enable Just My Code" is disabled.

EDIT:
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll doesn't load the symbols

When I go to the Modules' window and select "load symbols", VS loads it from the cache. 
It can't find the symbols for the Debugger anywhere else.

> C:\Desenvolvimento\Focagem\Gestinf\Código\Working Copy\TestWorkApp\bin\x86\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   f:\binaries\Intermediate\debugger\runtime.csproj__624416745\objr\x86\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   C:\Windows\symbols\dll\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   C:\Windows\dll\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   C:\Users\joao.santos\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.pdb\bbffb22f8979464b8744c7c973fbe2c01\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.pdb: Symbols loaded.

Comment: Have you got the "debug" configuration set (Build->Configuration Manager or on the little pull-down in the middle of the toolbar)?

Comment: Debug > Windows > Modules.  Locate your assembly in the list.  Right-click and select Symbol Load Information.  Check that it could find and open the PDB file.  Make sure the file is not corrupted and make an exclusion in your anti-malware so it cannot block access.

Comment: @BrianHooper, debug mode is set, thanks.

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks. Modules window indicates that Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll doesn't load the symbols. All the others load the symbols.